# What is the degree of the differential equation formed from $y= Ax + A^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

**Problem:-** What is the degree of the differential equation formed from  $y= Ax + A^3$

**Solution:-** $y= Ax + A^3$

Differentiating both sides we get

$y'= A$

Combining both eqations we get

$y= y'x + y'^3$

So degree is $3$

But answer is given  degree is $1$

Am I wrong or there is some mistake in the book

Comment: The question makes no sense. A part from a likely confusion about the *order* of a differentuial equation and the degree of a power, the question is pointless. It would be the same as to ask: "what is the degree of the polynomial formed fron 2?"!!!

Comment: Also we can write this question " Family of curves $y=Ax+A^3$ is represented by the differential equation of which degree"

Comment: I suppose the degree represents the maximum order of derivatives, so for order 3 you should have $y'''$ somewhere.

Comment: In the book where you found the answer of degree 1, what is their definition of the degree of a differential equation? ] This would be easy to answer if you have the book by using the index :-) ]

Comment: Its not that much standard book. Answers can be wrong there